# Invalid identifier while updating a column using cursor for loop?

Tags: plsql, cursor

I am trying to update salary column in my table using cursors.
This is my code:

```
declare
cursor c1 is
select * from emp2_1030082;
begin
for c3 in c1
loop
if(c3.salary>10000)
then
update emp2_1030082 set c3.salary=c3.salary + c3.salary/10 ;
elsif(c3.salary<=10000)
then
update emp2_1030082 set c3.salary= c3.salary + c3.salary/20 ;
end if;
end loop;
end;
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
 ORA-06550: line 9, column 47:
    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "C3"."SALARY": invalid identifier
    ORA-06550: line 9, column 1:
    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
    ORA-06550: line 12, column 25:
    PL/SQL: ORA-00904: "C3"."SALARY": invalid identifier
    ORA-06550: line 12, column 1:
    PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
    06550. 00000 -  "line %s, column %s:\n%s"
    *Cause:    Usually a PL/SQL compilation error.
    *Action:
```

Comment: please,help someone.

Answer (score 1):

The first question is, do you really need to do this in a cursor? Because executing these two statements should do what you want:

```
update emp2_1030082 set salary=salary + salary/10 where salary > 10000;
update emp2_1030082 set salary=salary + salary/20 where salary <= 10000;
```

Meanwhile, the error you are getting is because in

```
update emp2_1030082 set c3.salary=c3.salary + c3.salary/10 ;
```

By using the `c3.` in `set c3.salary` you are referring to the cursor instead of the column name in the table that you want to update. Just `salary` (and in the other update as well) should make the error go away, BUT, *you  will update all rows with every update*, so pretty sure that's not what you want.

To do it with a cursor, you should remove the the `c3.` from where it doesn't belong, and then add a where clause to update only the current record. Hopefully you have some kind of unique ID, and then it would be something like:

```
update emp2_1030082 set salary=c3.salary + c3.salary/10 where id = c3.id;
```

Comment: yes in the question it's mentioned that i have to use cursor,and yes using just salary is updating for every record ,i'll try and do it for the current record.